# When my game ends I need to 'send' the variable holding the score to a table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sprite-kit

When my game ends I need to 'send' the variable holding the score to a table view controller. I tried doing this through

```
//In LeaderboardTableVC.swift
var gameScore:Int! = 0

//In GameScene.swift
var leadVC: LeaderboardTableVC!
var score:Int = 0

func showLeaderboard(){

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let leaderBoardVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leaderboard")
    self.vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(leaderBoardVC, animated: true)
    leadVC.gameScore = score

}
```

However when I run the code an error occurs: 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value ' on the 'leadVC.gameScore = score' line of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `leadVC`? You instantiated a variable called `leaderBoardVC`, so that's whose `gameScore` you should update.

Comment: `leadVC` is nil. You never assigned anything to it.

Comment: Your code, and your learning experience, will be much better if you lay off of the `!` in your code. Your `gameScore` var shouldn't have a `!`, and your `leadVC` var should have a `?` instead of a `!`.

Comment: @DanielT. - I disagree with the oft-cited, categorical "always use `?` rather than `!`" counsel. If the variable should never be `nil`, then `!` is appropriate. It's better to know that the variable wasn't set like it was supposed to be, rather than silently proceeding, never knowing that it wasn't used properly and have the app not do what you expected.

Comment: @Rob, I didn't say "always" or "never" to do anything at all. In this particular case, having a `!` on `gameScore` is irrelevant and could lead into trouble if he accidentally assigns `nil` to it (which would be nonsensical.) And if he had use a `?` in leadVC instead of `!`, he would not be here asking us why he got the error he got. Instead he would have realized that `leadVC` might be nil and accounted for that.

Comment: Code that refuses to compile because you made a mistake is far better than code that crashes because you made a mistake... And code that crashes because you made a mistake is better than code that silently fails due to that mistake. I think we can agree on that, yes?

Comment: @DanielT. - FYI, it's not the `Int!` of `gameScore` that is the problem. It's the `!` in the declaration of `leadVC`. And when you say "better if you lay off of the `!` in your code", I took that as categorical counsel. But if you meant to say "only use `!` where appropriate", then I agree. But if you're only referring to `gameScore`, then I agree that the initializing it to 0 and declaring it an optional is poor design (though I think initializing it to zero is more problematic than the use of optionals).

Comment: @Rob *...If the variable should never be nil, then `!` is appropriate*. Actually in this case a non-optional is appropriate.

Comment: @vadian - Yes, you'd use non-optional if you can set it in `init`. But if it's something that is set later in the process (e.g. something that is always set in `prepareForSegue`), then implicitly unwrapped optional is fine. I simply tire of all of the knee-jerk "don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals" that I see here on S.O. (But I now gather that that was _not_ what Daniel intended, so my apologies to him.)

Comment: @Rob Implicit unwrapped optionals should **only** be used in declaration lines and if it's not possible to assign a initial value directly nor in the init method nor via lazy initialization, nowhere else. I'm glad that Swift 3 turns implicit unwrapped optionals into regular optionals in ambiguous cases.

Comment: @vadian - It's not merely when it's not technically "possible", but also where it's not "appropriate" (e.g. if you find yourself initializing your properties to some sentinel value). But with that one caveat, I agree with you.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing it out dumb mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated `leaderBoardVC`, but never set the `leadVC` property. Thus, `leadVC` is still `nil` when you try to set `gameScore`, and thus it crashes when it tries to do the forced unwrapping of this implicitly unwrapped optional.

Frankly, I'd probably retire the `leadVC` property, altogether, which avoids this problem altogether. Why do you need this property? Anyway, you can do:

```
//In GameScene.swift

// var leadVC: LeaderboardTableVC!
var score:Int = 0

func showLeaderboard(){

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let leaderBoardVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leaderboard") as? LeaderboardTableVC else {
        fatalError("Either couldn't find scene with `leaderboard` identifier, or its base class was not `LeaderboardTableVC`")
    }
    leaderBoardVC.gameScore = score
    self.vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(leaderBoardVC, animated: true)
}
```

Note, I'd probably set `gameScore` *before* pushing to it.

---

Alternatively, if you really needed this property, you'd do:

```
//In GameScene.swift
var leadVC: LeaderboardTableVC!
var score: Int = 0

func showLeaderboard() {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    leadVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leaderboard")
    leadVC.gameScore = score
    self.vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(leadVC, animated: true)
}
```

This just begs the question of why do you want to keep a strong reference to this `leadVC` (e.g. when you pop back, it's going to keep this in memory).